# Does tax evasion in the EU cost 1 trillion € per year?

Tags: europe, taxes

In a meme that’s floating around, various social costs are compared to tax evasion in the EU, which is claimed to mount up to 1 000 000 000 000 Euro annually.

Here is an example:

[image: Chart comparing 1 trillion in tax avoidance to 12.5 billion for 1 million refugees]

The Swedish text states that the cost for one million refugees is 12.5 billion €  compared to annual tax evasion of 1 000 billion €.

No source is given and a simple search doesn’t give any immediate hits.

Is this figure correct, given some reasonable estimate and calculation and is there a source behind the meme?

Comment: Hi Guran - can you provide an example of the meme, rather than referencing it obliquely?  Hearsay doesn't really fit the bill of "notable claim".

Comment: @jdunlop I edited in one example. Text is in Swedish unfortunately.

Comment: BTW this particular graphic originates from a politician named Lisa Pelling

Comment: https://ftalphaville.ft.com/2019/02/21/1550732404000/Europe-s--1-trillion-tax-gap/ cites a study that gives a fairly close figure of 750–800 G€. I have no idea how reliable that study is.

Comment: One of the EU's official sites [claims that the estimates of the avoidance "go up to € 1 trillion."](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/fight-against-tax-fraud-tax-evasion/a-huge-problem_en), but cite no studies.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between tax *avoidance* and tax *evasion*.  Tax avoidance is generally legal, employing loopholes and special exemptions.  Tax evasion is, by the most common definition, the use of illegal means to avoid taxes.

Comment: I think the claim is twofold: that 1 million refugees cost a state 12.5b euros, and that the yearly "cost" of tax avoidance/evasion in the EU is (on the order) of 1000b euros.

Comment: It's not the state who loses due to tax evasion/avoidance, but the tax-paying population. In the simple example there needs to be X amount of money in the national pot, and that is raised by charging Y tax payers Z% of their earnings/spending. If everybody paid the taxes that are due, the tax rates could be reduced.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The claim here is definitely for evasion.

Comment: @JohnW. It certainly is, but I’m specifically asking about the latter. (I’ve seen the same figure for tax evasion used in comparison to other allegedly much smaller cost as well)

Comment: @Guran - What constitutes "evasion" is quite sensitive to ones political (and economic) leanings.  And many references will muddle the two.

Comment: Cum-ex has been called the biggest tax scandal but is estimated below 100 billion (https://www.dw.com/en/cum-ex-tax-scandal-cost-european-treasuries-55-billion/a-45935370) - I assume that billion = 10^9 here

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yep. Any source that reached the sum in “avoidance” but required a dose of ideology to reach it in “evasion” would make a good answer.

Comment: 1000 billion € is not more than 2000€ per inhabitant in the EU. That does not sound entirely unplausible, but since this money is withheld public control, you won't get anything but estimates. Noone can for sure know how much money is involved.